# scp2 from Linux to Windows via batch script, *.* file mask issues

Tags: linux, batch-file, ssh, scp

I'm running a batch file that uses a .ini file to populate the scp2 command (F-Secure's scp2).  The batch file when triggered will complete a scp2 of data files from a remote Linux server to the local Windows server.

**INI FILE**:

```
REMOTE_FILE="*"
```

**BATCH FILE**:

```
"%SSH_HOME%\scp2" -k %KEYS% -o "AllowedAuthentications publickey" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking off" %USER%@%SERVER%:%REMOTE_DIR%/%REMOTE_FILE%.* %LOCAL_DIR% >> %LOG% 2>&1
```

When %REMOTE_FILE% was set to "x", this would happily collect all files x.*

However, since changing %REMOTE_FILE% to "*", the scp2 now tries to copy the sub directories on the remote server, which fails as I am not using -r, but also causes a non-zero error code of scp2 which affects subsequent processing in the batch file.

I am assuming that the operating system (not sure which one) is expanding the file mask but I cannot identify how to stop this behaviour and let scp2 expand the file mask.  I have tried setting the variable to "*", as well as putting the whole quotes around the whole user/passwd/directory/file , i.e

```
"%USER%@%SERVER%:%REMOTE_DIR%/%REMOTE_FILE%.*"
```

but with no success.  Any ideas out there, please?

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to copy just the files, since you are not bothering with the '-r' argument, then perhaps a change of the mask from "*" to "*.*" might get you what you want?